# Overlaying a Image with CSS

Tags: html, css, background, overlay, z-index

I have a store with a gallery. I was looking to overlay the Thumbnail if a Sold stamp that I made.

If i disable the image the overlay is showing bellow, so I know it is inserting the image, it isn't on top though.

What I see:

[image]

How I know the overlay is below (thumbnail disabled):

[image]

HTML:

```
<li class="post-66 product type-product status-publish has-post-thumbnail sold-individually shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-simple outofstock">
<center>
<a href="http://url.com">
<img width="150" height="150" src="thumbnail.jpg" class="attachment-shop_catalog wp-post-image" alt="coelho1" />
<h3>Coelho de Peluxe</h3>
</a>
</center>
</li>
```

CSS:

```
.outofstock { 
background: url("soldoverlay.png") top left no-repeat;
position: relative; 
z-index: 200;
}
.attachment-shop_catalog{
z-index: 1;
}
```

Can anyone please help me?

Kind Regards

Comment: The `<center>` element has been deprecated and should no longer be used.

Comment: A demo would be of some help/

Comment: Playu around with z-index property. Higher one comes on the top. If you are using out of the box modal plugin, some of them tend to set z-index to 1000, so try something higher.

Comment: You are setting that overlay as a background-image .... so it's alwasy under the img tag

Comment: @Paulie_D http://daily-crochet.cf/ the 3rd Product, First one with thumbnail is the only one with the Sold attribute.

Comment: @DanielPinzon how do I set through css a overlayer then

Comment: @Paulie_D you can easily see it by editing the src to something random: http://gyazo.com/2624c3d4a4f09dffc9c08e76be8e3f27

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to make an overlay is use a `pseudo-element` using the class you already have `outofstock`. Check this snippet as an example:

```css
li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align:center;
  margin:10px;
}
.outofstock:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="http://url.com">
      <img width="150" height="150" src="http://placehold.it/150" alt="coelho1" />
      <h3>WITHOUT OVERLAY</h3>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="outofstock">
    <a href="http://url.com">
      <img width="150" height="150" src="http://placehold.it/150" alt="coelho1" />
      <h3>OVERLAY</h3>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

#### Edit

To keep the link to of the `href` you can create the pseudo-element inside the `a` tag like this:

```css
li {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
}
a {
  position: relative;
  display:block;
}
.outofstock a:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="http://url.com">
      <img width="150" height="150" src="http://placehold.it/150" alt="coelho1" />
      <h3>WITHOUT OVERLAY</h3>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="outofstock">
    <a href="http://url.com">
      <img width="150" height="150" src="http://placehold.it/150" alt="coelho1" />
      <h3>OVERLAY</h3>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: .outofstock:after { 
  content:url("http://daily-crochet.cf/vendido.png");
  position:absolute;
  top:0; 
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  z-index: 10;
}
Worked. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Looks nice on your web @PedroFrazão glad to help U mate.

Comment: I doesn't connect to the next page anymore. Is there anyway to keep the href from the thumbnail?

Comment: @PedroFrazão since the overlay is now over the entire `a` tag that can be tricky but what you can do is change your selector and instead of target the `li` target the `a`element....Check this Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zzdo4eh1/

Comment: It is openning the page. As the product carries the SOLD attribute through the page to disable the buy button etc, It added the overlay in the Main Thumbnail but it also added on a Tab. http://daily-crochet.cf/?product=awdawdawawddawa

Comment: @PedroFrazão you will need to make more specific your selectors use this: `li.outofstock a:after, .outofstock > .images a:after`

Comment: Well literally all page is a href now :P

Comment: @PedroFrazão seems like it's because you place the class `outofstock` on the main div container .... you can try giving the class to the `images` div = `<div class="images outofstock">` and remember change the selector again to: `li.outofstock a:after, .outofstock.images > a:after`

Comment: The classes on are affecting all the product so I will take the shortcut and only use li.outofstock a:after and it only displays on the Gallery page. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you could avoid to use an image and play with CSS 2D transformations (supported even on `IE9`)

e.g. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NPydBP

Markup

```
<ul>
  <li data-in-stock="vendido">
     <a href=""> 
       <img src="http://dummyimage.com/400x280/cccccc/fff.jpg"  />
     </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
li {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

[data-in-stock]:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;

  content: attr(data-in-stock);
  display: block;

  min-width: 160px; 
  color: #fff;
  background: #222;
  padding: 6px 10px;

  text-transform: uppercase;
  font: 1em Arial;

  -webkit-transform: rotate(-42deg) translateX(-50px);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-42deg) translateX(-50px);
  transform: rotate(-42deg) translateX(-50px);
}
```

The text overlapped comes from the `data-in-stock` attribute in the markup, so you can easily change the text or optionally serve a different page language

This approach could also work if you need to show an image instead of a text (the content property also accepts an url to an image): see http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dPdNBQ

---

Final Result

[image]

Comment: Nice it will provide a nice solution if the overlay needed is jsut the text :) +1

Comment: @DanielPinzon optionally with the content property you may also provide an url to an image

Comment: Thank you for the help but i will apply what im doing in also other content  and I will need to use an Image

Comment: @PedroFrazão see my previous comment. You can still use an image in place of a text

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a DIV to place your image in, set left and top css, and set z-index to 5, set width and height to be same as image

2) Create another DIV with same left, top, width, and height, but set z-index higher. Place img tag with outofstock in it